How to move/copy files from ADLS Containers to GCS Bucket?
I have some files in ADLS Containers and I need to copy or move those files to GCS Bucket in certain interval.
Can someone suggest what are the current option we have to achieve this?

Well, it depends on your requirement. Can you provide what are the options that you have tried so far? and any blockers or errors?

@RakeshGovindula Initially I was using Databricks with PySpark where I was able to copy the files from ADLS to GCS when using a single tenant app. But while using a multi-tenant app, I started getting issue where it needs 'additionallyAllowedTenants' flag to pass '*' for DefaultAzureCredentials. But I was using Azure Service Principle, so can't use DefaultAzureCredentials there.

Doing a fast research in GCP website I found out that the native tool offered by Google for these task is Storage Transfer Service [1].
It says that depending on your source type, you can easily create and run Google-managed transfers, or configure self-hosted transfers that give you full control over network routing and bandwidth usage.
It is specified that ADLS sources are supported [2].
You can configure access to source data in Microsoft Azure Storage using shared access signatures (SAS) [3]. In particular you will need to create an SAS token at the container level. See Grant limited access to Azure Storage resources using shared access signatures for instructions [4].
You can save your Azure SAS token in Google Secret Manager [5].
The acces to GCS will be managed by creating Storage Transfer Service with a Service Account which has the rights to STS jobs [6], permissions to use the Secret Manager API and of course access to the GCS destination.
This would be the native option. Otherwise you would have also some third party tools like Apache NiFi, in cases like this one you will need an access token from both source and destionation storage system.
[1] STS
https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/overview#:~:text=Storage%20Transfer%20Service%20automates,to%20write%20any%20code.
[2] Supported sources
https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/sources-and-sinks#:~:text=Azure%20Blob%20Storage%2C%20including%20Azure%20Data%20Lake%20Storage%20Gen2
[3] Access
https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/source-microsoft-azure#:~:text=You%20can%20configure%20access%20to%20source%20data%20in%20Microsoft%20Azure%20Storage%20using%20shared%20access%20signatures%20(SAS).
[4] Azure Limited Access to storage with SAS
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-sas-overview
[5] Secret Manager
https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/source-microsoft-azure#secret_manager
[6] STS job permissions
https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/access-control#jobs
